How can I blind the comparator after a certain period of time?
I am trying to catch a fast event signal. You can see the circuit I set up for this purpose below. I am using the LTC6752 as a comparator. I chose this comparator because of its high speed and low propagation delay. While the negative terminal of the comparator has a voltage of 500mV, the voltage applied to the positive terminal is as follows (V_source). The pulse that is meaningful to me is the first pulse(main), which lasts a total of 2ns. I do not want to see the secondary pulse, which lasts about 10ns, at the output of the comparator. I want to blind the circuit 2ns after the main pulse comes. Since I don't know the exact amplitude of the pulse, I can't increase the voltage at the negative pin. How can I do this?



If you know the amplitudes of the pulses and if they are consistent throughout the entire operation then adjust the comparator reference (e.g. push it to 1.6 V).

add a diode between V_source and V_comp_neg

@JasenСлаваУкраїні this works in theory but does it work in this application? I was messing around with this in spice and it seems the forward response time of the diode would need to be faster than what I think is the fastest schottky I could find on digikey.

Have you considered a comparator with enable pin?

I think I have an answer. To blind the comparator to the subsequent pulse after the first one, I can momentarily raise the voltage at the negative pin of the comparator immediately after the first pulse. This way, the comparator won't detect the secondary signal. Assuming the first pulse lasts about 2ns, the flip-flop one-shot circuit I added will hold the output high for a specific duration (determined by R21-C6) when the rising edge of the first pulse occurs. The chosen flip-flop is SN74AUC1G74DCTR, which has a 1.8ns propagation delay and an output voltage of 2.5V. It works in the simulation environment, but I'm not sure what will happen when implemented.If you have any other ideas on this topic, I would appreciate your valuable contributions.



If the propagation delay of the flip-flop is very small, then, it can filter the first pulse also at the comparator output isn't it? What about using V_comp_out as the CLK for the flip-flop? That way, it will ensure that you'll get a finite pulse width

Instead of changing the V_comp_neg using the one-shot, why not just use the Q of the flip-flop output directly to connect to R17 instead of V_comp_out? Would that work for your application?

For propagation delays this short you don't need a flip-flop. An inverter, or a couple of them in series, will do the job well.

I wouldn't mess with too much analogue additions to the digital gates. It's hard to get it right. All you seem to want is to have a short 2ns pulse when the comparator output goes up, and nothing when the comparator output goes down. No need to move the comparator threshold.
Below is a positive edge detector. Adjust the length of the output pulse by changing the delay through the NOT1-NOT2 branch by adding gates or changing the gates to slower ones.
NOT1-NOT2-XOR1 is a bipolar edge detector. AND1 filters out positive edges only. The delays stack up so that there are no races.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
